# How can I remove a div with delay on mouseout/mouseleave?

Tags: jquery, hide, delay, mouseleave

I'm trying to make a function with delay. When I click on some paragraph, *MENU* is prepended to this paragraph. But I need to hide *MENU* when `mouseleave` or `mouseout` with delay.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/bZLAv/

**HTML**

```
<p class="add_to_this1">Click here 1</p>
<p class="add_to_this2">Click here 2</p>
<p class="add_to_this3">Click here 3</p>

<div id="menu"> I'm here</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.fn.handler = function () {
    $(this).on({
        click: function(e) {
            if ($(this).find("#menu").length) {
                return;
            }
            $('#menu').prependTo($(this));
            $("#menu").css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: "100px"
            }).show();
        }
    });
}
$(".add_to_this1").handler();
$(".add_to_this2").handler();
$(".add_to_this3").handler();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? In the current code there is nothing related to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84nVQ/1/) example

```
jQuery.fn.handler = function () {
    $(this).on({
        click: function(e) {
            if ($(this).find("#menu").length) {
                return;
            }

            $('#menu').prependTo($(this));

            $("#menu").css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: "100px"
            }).show();
        }
    });
}
$(".add_to_this1").handler();
$(".add_to_this2").handler();
$(".add_to_this3").handler();

$('p[class^=add_to_this]').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#menu').hide();
    }, 2000);        
});
```

​